# recovery service vault in azure bicep

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I tried creating a recovery service vault for site recovery though bicep.

Below recovery service vault properties not allowed in azure bicep. same script working arm template.How to fix this issue. thanks in advance.

1. Source Vnet ID & target vnet id

   Script for sie recovery through arm template working fine.

   ```
   "recoveryservicesvaults": [
       {
         "skipdeployment": "true",
         "name": "My-prod-rsv",
         "identity": "None",
         "enableDiagnostics": true,
         "enableSiterecovery": true,
         "sourceVNetId": "",
         "targetVNetId": ""
       }
     ],
   ```

Iam tried add source vnet id & target vnet id while deploying recovery service vault though azure bicep. its not allowing. But its working fine in arm template.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a recovery service vault without adding any recoveryservicevaults in properties block as you used and it was successful as shown.
Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/quickstart-create-vault-bicep?tabs=CLI) for the sample bicep template.

```bash
param  vaultName  string = 'newvjvault'
param  enableCRR  bool = true
param  vaultStorageType  string = 'GeoRedundant'
@description('Location for all resources.')
param  location  string = resourceGroup().location
resource  recoveryServicesVault  'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults@2022-02-01' = {
name: vaultName
location: location
sku: {
name: sku
tier: skuTier
}
properties: {}
}
resource  vaultName_vaultstorageconfig  'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupstorageconfig@2022-02-01' = {
parent: recoveryServicesVault
name: 'xxxx'
properties: {
storageModelType: vaultStorageType
crossRegionRestoreFlag: enableCRR
}
}
```

*Output:*

[image]

[image]

*Note:* Some properties present in ARM templates may not be immediately exposed in the Bicep language if the Bicep team has not yet provided support for them.

In that case, you can use deployments templates by adding the relevant ARM template `JSON` file with the `templateLink` block as follows:

```bash
templateLink: { 
uri: 'path of the arm template(JSON) file' 
}
```

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.resources/2021-01-01/deployments?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) for the detailed resource deployment template to achieve your requirement.